# Refreshing Fragments of ActionBar Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm writing an Android App in which I'm using an ActionBar with tabs. When the user presses a reload-button I remove all tabs and create new ones based on new data. I have the problem that after I've done this, the old contents of the current Fragment and the Fragments that are on the left and on the right of it in the ActionBar are still shown. But when I go to anoter tab, I see the new content. I've tried to also call removeAllViews on the ViewPager but the I get empty Fragments when I reload.

I think I already saw solutions for a similar problem on the internet, but it was with a TabHost and I don't know how to get the TabHost of the ActionBar.

To replace the Tabs, I use this code:

```
        actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(0));
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();
        for(int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++)
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(MainActivity.this));
```

After I've done this, I still see the old Fragment with its old content, so it seems that nothing happened. But when i tap on another Tab, I get the new content of the other Tabs Fragment and when I go back to the first Tab, it also refreshes the content.

My FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TagTabFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(tage != null)
            return tage.getLength();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tage.item(position).getAttributes().getNamedItem("datum").getTextContent();
    }
```

}

Comment: i did'nt got your questin.  you current fragment is not loading new data is that your problem??? it's better if you could post your code..

Comment: I replace the Fragments by new ones but the old ones are still shown until I tap on another tab (which isn't a direct neighbour of the current Tab).

Comment: You need to replace the fragment in your refresh functionality. I think you are replacing it now on tap of tab. So that's why untill U tap the tab it shows old one.. Can u post the code where you are replacing the fragments.

Comment: But how can I replace the Fragments directly. I delete all Tabs and create new ones and the SectionsPagerAdapter returns new Fragments when getItem() is called.